# Twitter webhook registration error | {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

when I try to register the twitter web-hook, api returns the error message **"Could not authenticate you"**.
I am using the below php wrapper for twitter api v1.1.

[twitter-api-php](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php)

```
$settings = array(
 'oauth_access_token' => $accesstoken,
 'oauth_access_token_secret' => $accesstokensecret,
 'consumer_key' => $consumerkey,
 'consumer_secret' => $consumersecret
);
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/all/msgdev/webhooks.json?url=https://myapp.com/twitterwebhook.php';
$requestMethod = 'POST';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

echo $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest();
```

I am able to send message. But not able to create webhook.
Created developer account and got api access, also created twitter app in apps.twitter.com

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this issue by doing a url-encode on your URL parameter. Refer the sample code on how we are doing it in ruby.

```
response = @twitter_api.post('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/all/chatwootdev/webhooks.json?url=https%3A%2F%2Fchatwoot.com%2F16b66d68-c9f9-4c2e-8caa-4244cff8b483', nil, HEADERS)
```

Also note that you will need to implement a CRC check at your webhook url before you start getting the events from twitter.  If the CRC is not implemented. you will be recieveing  `214` error code.

ref: [getting started with twitter accounts subscription api](https://medium.com/@nragusa/getting-started-with-the-twitter-account-activity-api-beta-395e9498af81)